# Excel horizontal Data

Tags: excel, transform, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has data going across the top as follows:

[image: see this image]

How do I get it so that the items which are going across the top horizontal is vertical

something like 
[image: this]

I am going to be receiving data in this way which potentially could have lots of data, so doing manually one by one would be difficult

I have tried using the transform option but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please understand that this is not a free code writing service. Therefore you will need to show what you already tried yourself. People are here to help others with issues in code they have already written themselves, not to do all the work for them. So I suggest to start on your own and come back with your code and a specific question to it, so we can help you with the issues you have with that code.

Comment: Im not asking for anyone to do the work for me, i am asking for a little guidance. I have tried using the transform function in excel.

Comment: You need to write a vba code for that.

Comment: I'd suggest loading the data into a 2D array and then transpose that data, seems like it'd be an easy solution

Comment: Can you show an example of how you would like your data to be displayed vertically?

Comment: added image to comments

Comment: As I said you will need to write a VBA code to achieve exactly what you want. Therefore you will need to start writing code on your own, because asking for *how to implement something* is too broad to answer and off-topic because it would lead into opinion based answers (there is always more than one way to implement something). This is a question/answer based website where you need to ask a *specific* question. This site is not meant for longer guidance or broad teaching, therefore you would be better in better hands at a forum based website where someone can guide and teach you.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably redo this as a [PivotTable](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-A9A84538-BFE9-40A9-A8E9-F99134456576) if you wanted to avoid using vba. This would likely require you to reformat your inputs a little bit but I think it could work